# FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY sample

Tags: android

Can anyone provide an example how can I check does some file have a flag FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY assigned?
Any tested sample is very much welcomed.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**You will need these methods** (taken from [android code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:documentfile/documentfile/src/main/java/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentsContractApi19.java))

```
    private static int queryForInt(Context context, Uri self, String column,
                                   int defaultValue) {
        return (int) queryForLong(context, self, column, defaultValue);
    }
    private static long queryForLong(Context context, Uri self, String column,
                                     long defaultValue) {
        final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = resolver.query(self, new String[] { column }, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst() && !c.isNull(0)) {
                return c.getLong(0);
            } else {
                return defaultValue;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("My", "Failed query: " + e);
            return defaultValue;
        } finally {
            closeQuietly(c);
        }
    }
    private static void closeQuietly(@Nullable AutoCloseable closeable) {
        if (closeable != null) {
            try {
                closeable.close();
            } catch (RuntimeException rethrown) {
                throw rethrown;
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
```

**Then call them this way** (put your document uri in the parameter in place of `docUri`). For me the URI is a treeUri (I don't know if this is mandatory) containing an URI looking like `content://....`

```
    int columnFlagsValue =  queryForInt(this, docUri, DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_FLAGS,0);
    Log.i("MyLog", "columnFlagsValue: " + columnFlagsValue);
```

Then, convert the decimal value of columnFlagsValue you get to a binary value.

For example 326 (base10) will be  0b`101000110` (base2)
According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.Document#FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY) `FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY` has `Constant Value: 128 (0x00000080)` Which is in binary 0b`10000000` (see the `1` at position 8 when starting from the right).

On 0b`101000110` there is a 0 at position 8 from the right.

So, value for FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY is OFF in my example of 326.

```
dec:      326               128
bin:   101000110         10000000
        ^                ^ 
       OFF               ON
```

**To check programatically** you can do something like `if ((flags & 128) == 128)...` if true, it means FLAG_SUPPORTS_COPY is set.